# Invalid Resx ... Access is denied; but to WHAT?

Tags: visual-studio, assemblies, telerik, resx

I have a .NET project that simply cannot be built on my system, because every .Resx file fails with this error:

```
Invalid Resx file. Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Reporting, Version=4.1.10.714, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied. Line 122, position 5.    C:\...\SomeReport.resx
```

The line (element) in question is:

```
  <metadata name="$this.SnapGridSize" type="Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit, Telerik.Reporting, Version=3.2.9.1104, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be">
    <value>0.1in</value>
  </metadata>
```

Otherwise the project relies on Telerik Reporting assemblies and everything works fine if I just remove all of the metadata elements from all of the Resx files before building. For various reasons, these metadata elements get back into the project constantly.

So how can I tell WHAT file access is denied to? I can't seem to get any hints from Visual Studio here, and it's driving me absolutely insane.

Comment: Have you tried watching things with ProcesMon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see where something might be denied access?

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea. I tried process explorer but that isn't quite real-time enough!